# How to assign a token to a user

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, metamask

Written a Dapp with solidity and connected it with a webpage. For now, because i'm in the developing stage, i'm using the Ropsten Test Network to make sure my Dapp runs properly before deploying it on my node.

For now i'm learning how to connect my Dapp through Localhost 8545. What i understand is, if public users were to use my node, the gases used by them will be charged to me.

1. Is it true?
2. How do i connect users to my node to use my dapp

Comment: 1. yes and no, depends on your implementation. You could implement a raw transaction system where you pass the raw (unsigned) transaction to the user, the user signs it and you push the transaction to your node (but the payer, in this case, is the user) 2. Depends on your implementation again :) but I would integrate with Metamask or Trezor for the raw transaction signing part. You could elaborate a little your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Users don't use your node, users use your web application. Your web application connects to an ethereum node and sends transactions and calls contracts via that node.

So you all you have to do is to make your app to connect to a node.

Here is an awesome tutorial: https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-gentle-intro-to-building-a-full-stack-dapp-on-ethereum-part-1-c1aedb11fcd2